# Backslash in Python using r"

Tags: python

I just started to learn Python. I know using r" indicates that backlash will be presented as backslash itself. but when I use the following two expressions, the results are different. Why?

```
>>> a = r"\ "
>>> a
'\\ '
>>> print(a)
\
```

Comment: NB: why the parentheses? These are not necessary.

Comment: Note: use a code block to show code; without it, in your initial version of the question, the double backslash disappeared and was shown as a single backslash, making things more confusing.

Comment: The first example is `a`, and the second example is `print(a)`.  Those are obviously different.  Why are you surprised that the _result_ is different?

Comment: Check out the docs for [`repr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr) and [`str`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str).

Comment: Fun thing: also try `repr(a)` and `str(a)`, for more confusion.

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.